# Adding SVG attributes to a class

Tags: html, css, svg, styling

I am making an image using SVG, and many elements have the same attributes, i.e a typical element looks like:

```
<line x1="30" y1="10" x2="270" y2="10" stroke-width="0.1" stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="2.5 2.5"/>
```

There are many of these types of line, where the only things that change are the coordinates. There must be a way to make some sort of class containing the attributes of stroke-width, stroke, and stroke-dasharray? I am repeating myself a lot and it's clogging up the code a bit.

I've tried with CSS but I can't get SVG attributes working with it. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Please add some code sample. There is no reason why CSS wouldn't work with SVG. Eg. `line {stroke: lightgray, stroke-dasharray: 2.5, 2.5; }` etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes#Using_CSS

Comment: Have you tried implementing this in javascript? Or are you trying to go with a purely css/html path?

Comment: These [styling properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) can be used both as attributes and as CSS styles.

Answer (score 1):

Style attributes can inherit from their parent elements.  So if you have a bunch of lines with the same properties, then just wrap them in a group and apply the properties to that.

```
<g stroke-width="0.1" stroke="lightgray" stroke-dasharray="2.5 2.5"/>
  <line x1="30" y1="10" x2="270" y2="10"/>
  <line x1="40" y1="10" x2="270" y2="30"/>
  ...etc...
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @ccprog, there a some [styling attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) which can be set using css. All other properties like `x` and `y` need to be set on the element itself.

If you have a lot repetition going on, you can consider using the `<defs>` and `<use>` like so:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <line id="line-1" x="..." ... />
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#line-1" transform="translate(...)" />
  <use xlink:href="#line-1" transform="rotate(...)" />
  <use xlink:href="#line-1" transform="translate(...) rotate(...)" />
  .
  .
  .
</svg>
```

This way you can reuse the line as is, but you are limited to transforms when it comes to rearrange them.

Please note thet in SVG 2.0 the use of `xlink:href` is depricated in favor of just `href` in `<use>` element.